# Which equation can we use for a ball that is constantly bouncing on the ground?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

In the above mentioned case, you take the ball as:- in both vertical motion (bouncing) and also horizontal motion (velocity).
Can I even consider the amount of force/pressure it exerts on the ground while it travels?
I was actually looking to relate the force in that equation.

Comment: What have you tried? How would you generally model a particle under the influence of a force?

Comment: I was thinking of this the other day. Since earth is more like an ellipsoid than a sphere the gravitational pull is probably not directed exactly down. And then it rotates and wobbles too so you have those effects to weigh in. And then you have clouds and moisture and winds.

Comment: I tried to solve it but haven't solved problems for years so it is probably wrong :( : $$
T(x,p;m)=\frac{1}{2m}\langle p,p\rangle\\
U(x,p;m)=m\langle -g\hat{z},x\rangle\\
L=T-U\\
0=\partial_xL-d_t\partial_pL=-mg -d_t\frac{1}{m}p
$$

Comment: My potential energy is "wrong", should be more similar to GmM/r but don't remember how

Comment: @heather Feels like I hijacked Sandesh's question...

Comment: Hi Sandesh N. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: In particular, the math phys tag is not applicable.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are dropping from a height s.
$$s=\frac{1}{2} gt^2$$
$$v_{impact}=gt_{fall}$$
so $$v_{impact}=\sqrt{2sg}$$
But for the force of the impact you have to know that way the object will hit the "ground" - the force of falling from 10m to hit concrete is not the same as hitting water (or at least mud if you want to consider ground). In any case the force is going to scale with $mv$.